# Laravel - mariaDB connection refused

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mariadb-10.1

On my new laptop, I've windows 10 with ubuntu bash. mariadb 10.1 working fine and trying to config my Laravel projects. But when I try to login on Laravel 5.6 I get the message: "Connection refused"

I try into DB_HOST my local IP and 127.0.0.1
I checked all connections, clean cache from Laravel, try connection to mysql from command line.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Ideas?

Comment: Can you show us the exact error message you've received, as well as the database settings for mysql in config/database.php? (I'm no expert, but it will help others with more knowledge about databases)

Answer (score 0):

In XAMPP, By default accessing the phpmyadmin doesn't require password. Try removing yours.